# How to plug a value entered in an overloaded >> operator into a setter

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I really really apologize if this has already been asked. I'm sincerely trying to become more literate with the site, but still struggle with specific questions. Anyways, I've figured out how to overload the ">>" operator, but I'm now struggling with how to set the value determined in that function as a variable (Sorry if none of this makes sense)

Here's what I have for the overloaded >> function

```
istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rectangle& inSides)
{
double insSide1, insSide2;

ins >> insSide1;

insSide1 = inSides._length;

ins >> insSide2;

insSide2 = inSides._width;

return ins;
}
```

Here's what I have so far in my main()

```
Rectangle bothOpp;
{
        cin >> bothOpp;

        bothOpp.getLength();
        bothOpp.getWidth();

        bothOpp.print();

}
```

I guess what I'm asking is how do I set the user's input to be the value defined in the setter? Thank you so much for your time (:

Oh & if need be I can upload the setter function I have created, I just didn't want to bombard you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need to modify `inSides`**.

You get the input you need to construct a `Rectangle` object, but you never do anything with it! Try this (making some assumptions about your `Rectangle` class...):

```
istream& operator >> (istream& ins, Rectangle& inSides)
{
    double len, wid;
    ins >> len >> wid;

    inSides = Rectangle(len, wid);
    //or if you haven't made a constructor/assignment operator...
    inSides._length = len;
    inSides._width = wid;

    return ins;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! The area equation I have works now!! I've upvoted but I'm pretty sure it doesn't really matter given my reputation. You're awesome (: